# Model delete() and deserialized_object.save() calls don't work if called consecutively

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import json to my django webapp and its almost working fine except one problem. When I delete the objects 1-2 lines before calling  deserialized_object.save()  it works fine but if I call delete() and then save() consecutively it does not work properly.

THIS WORKS FINE

```
def builder_import(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['myfile']
        data = file.read()
        ModelOne.objects.filter(linked__name__pk=pk).delete()
        for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
            if object_should_be_saved(deserialized_object):
                deserialized_object.save()
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
def builder_import(request, pk):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.FILES['myfile']
    data = file.read()
    for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
      if object_should_be_saved(deserialized_object):
        ModelOne.objects.filter(linked__name__pk=pk).delete()
        deserialized_object.save()
```

The first snippet works fine but the second snippet does not. In First case it deletes all entries and then uploads everything correctly in DB. But in second case it deletes and then uploads only one entry for some strange reason.

May be it is some Synchronization issue but I thought django DB operations and well synchronized.

What could be wrong?
(I have followed following guide for serialization https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization) (edited)

Comment: Your question lacks data model details, however, I think everything works just fine. Each iteration adds single record, next iteration deletes it, then adds another one. Eventually you have _one record created_. PK stays the same in each iteration so deleting again and again does not look as a fine design in any case.

Comment: Oh that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As commented above:

Each iteration adds single record, next iteration deletes it, then adds another one. Eventually you have one record created. PK stays the same in each iteration so deleting again and again does not look as a fine design in any case.